# Plot barplot horizontaly for two groups using positive x axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Given the following matrix

```
df <- matrix(c(10,8, 20, 6, 20, 25,"exp", "cnt", "exp","cnt","exp","cnt","gene1","gene1","gene2","gene2","gene3","gene3"), 
nrow=6, dimnames=list(c("1", "2", "3","4","5","6"),c("Abundance", "Group","gene")  ))
```

I would like to plot horizontally the barplot for two groups "exp" and "cnt" separated by a vertical line at zero, the y axis displaying positive values corresponding to each gene and the gene name in the x axis. 
Here an example:

[image: barplot]

I tried the following code using ggplot but it didn't work.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=gene))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=Abundance, fill="exp"), stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(aes(y=-Abundance, fill="cnt"),  stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual("Group",values=c(exp="red",cnt="green"))+
  labs(y="Abundance")+coord_flip()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Here's why it's good to be specific: when I run your code, I get an error message that tells me very clearly that the data needs to be a data frame. Are you getting something else?

Comment: Yes..that's true. In addition to the generation of a data frame, I encountering some problems to set positive x values for both groups and to display correct gene values corresponding to each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right but you're problem is that your making your data.frame a matrix. ggplot only takes data.frames as input. A second problem is that matrices can only hold one data type, so it's casting everything as a character (Thus it will give an error when you try to make Abundance negative)

Put your data in a data.frame and it will work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Abundance = c(10, 8, 20, 6, 20, 25), 
             Group = c("exp", "cnt", "exp", "cnt", "exp", "cnt"),
             gene = rep(paste0("gene", 1:3), each = 2))
df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Abundance Group gene 
#>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1        10 exp   gene1
#> 2         8 cnt   gene1
#> 3        20 exp   gene2
#> 4         6 cnt   gene2
#> 5        20 exp   gene3
#> 6        25 cnt   gene3

ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(data = filter(df, Group == "cnt"), 
             aes(x = gene, y = Abundance, fill = Group),
             stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + 
    geom_bar(data = filter(df, Group == "exp"), 
             aes(x = gene, y = -Abundance, fill = Group), 
             stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + 
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the plot is displaying the same value for both groups while in the df they are different for each gene. Running a similar script I encountered the same issues (specular values and negative/positive axis). Do you know how to set the x axis at positive values for both groups and display bars corresponding to value for each gene/group?